# Is my Ubuntu Installation Corrupt?

Tags: system-installation

I just messed everything up so badly on my computer after I downloaded Ubuntu and deleted windows off the hard drive. Now I can only turn the computer on and come to the log on screen, then when I log on BAM I get a message that it has failed to do so.

I have a feeling that some files are corrupt and since I have not been ever to use Ubuntu on the computer, I decided it would be best to simply reinstall Ubuntu. But how?

The computer is an old one and I have found tutorials for reinstalling Ubuntu while the computer is working, but what if its not?

Comment: Use a computer that is working to prepare a disc to install on the machine that is now not working.

Comment: Do what Elliott said and don't delete Windows so soon ever.